# How to get feed title in correct language?

Tags: 8, feeds

In Drupal 8.2 I have rss default feeds on front page and feeds on my views. 
On the bottom of the pages I can click on the feed icon to open the feed page.

On the feed pages the feed titles are not in the correct language. The feed titles appear always in the language the node was created.

But I need the correct language for the feed title when switching to another language on my drupal site (/en/..., /fr/....).

And the feed title links to the wrong language.

How can I repair this problem in Drupal 8.2?